# django: customized token authentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am doing APIs, and trying to use token. I want to achieve:
1, client issues a request to server with token in the header;
2, server verify the token and do something (one time).

Looking into the [DRF](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py#L43), If I would like to overwrite the authenticate function, I also need to return User object or our own customized User object. I would not like to return any User object, because the whole process does not involve any User, just token and permission to do something. How to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First of all, create *modelToken* in models.py. Furthermore, you need to create a *token_required* decorator. Whenever a user logs in, a token is created, and whenever she/he logs out, the token is destroyed.

**login**:

```
def login(request):
    username=request.payload.get('username')
    password=request.payload.get('password')
    user,err=Auth.authenticate(username,password)
    if err:
        raise Exception()
    token=Token.generate()
    #you can return user
    return {'token':token}
```

**decorators**:

```
def token_required(func):
    def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            request.token=Token.objects.get(token=token)
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Token.DoesNotExists:
            pass
    return inner
```

**logout**:

```
@token_required
def logout(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        request.token.delete()
        return {'status':'ok'}
```

Comment: Its a great solution.  But some tweaking has to be done for making it work